# WooCommerce set specific currency on site shop

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

The challenge is the following:
How to set the output price converted in local currency in frontend site shop? We need to have base price in USD in admin area, but on the site shop we need to use local currency without possibility to select any other currencies, just strictly show prices converted in local currency.

I've used woocommerce currency converter plugin but it works as a widget and not on all shop areas, and I need to show prices in local currencies and without currency selector widget.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I've just ran into your question, and of course it was almost a year, so, I'm not sure if you've solved the issue. I'll put an answer here in case you still didn't (which I doubt), and for other people may be searching for an answer.
My suggestion is to go with JQuery on the Front End to replace the price and the currency symbol based on the visitor selected country or the admin's set local currency.

In the admin set model, based on the StoreFront Theme:

- First, you enqueue a JQuery script that will make the change, this goes in you main plugin page:

  add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_local_currency_changer' );
  function add_local_currency_changer() {
      wp_enqueue_script('local_currency_changer', // name your script so that you can attach other scripts and de-register, etc.
      '/wp-content/plugins/YOUR-PLUGIN-DIR/js/local_currency_changer.js', // this is the location of your script file
      array('jquery') // this array lists the scripts upon which your script depends
      );
  }
- Second, you create the JQuery script which should be similar to:

  ```
  <script>
      jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
          $(".woocommerce-price-amount"). innerHTML('<span class="woocommerce-Price-  currencySymbol">--YOUR NEW LOCAL CURRENCY SYMBOL HERE--</span>');
          $(this).append("--YOUR NEW LOCAL PRICE HERE--");
      })
  </script>
  ```

Please note that I didn't test the above code. Still, it is just a suggestion for the direction where you would be heading.

Also, please note that "--YOUR NEW LOCAL PRICE HERE--" can be a complex calculation or even may use Ajax to call a dynamic rate service such as Google...etc, and not just a static text.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

There are many plugin provide these kind of functionality. You need to research for the same some plugin which can help you achieve you goal are as follows:

- [WooCommerce Currency Switcher](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-currency-switcher/)
  This Plugin allows you to switch to different currencies and get their rates converted in the real time
- [WooCommerce Multilingual - run WooCommerce with WPML](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-multilingual/)
  This plugin makes it possible to run fully multilingual e-commerce sites using WooCommerce and WPML. It makes products and store pages translatable, lets visitors switch languages and order products in their language.

These are some of the plugins which enables running a single WooCommerce store with multiple currencies.

Comment: Answers should be more than plain links. Please see [answer]